# Overiding angularjs function $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$http.get(url).success(function(response,status,header,config) {
    $scope.mymodel = response;
}
```

I want to check the http status and call a function.
I have to do this change on about 100 `http.get` calls in whole project. So I want to skip this overriding the success function like this.

```
function success(response,status,header,config) {
    if(status!=200){
       //my stuff
    }
    super.success(response,status,header,config);
}
```

Another possibility is `replace $http.get(url).success` for `$http.get(url).success2` in order to tell my mates: `"From now on guys use $http.get(url).success2 is cooler!"`

## **Update**

I have already know is a deprecated function, I must use it because is a project requirement.

Comment: Check out the [http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Comment: You can parameter the $http service. Go on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and section "Interceptors".

Comment: worth noting, `.success` is deprecated, and `.then` should be used instead.

Comment: What do you wish to do if the status is 200? An interceptor would be perfect for minimizing duplication. However it will limit what exactly you can do when your in that if block.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$httpProvider.interceptors` to achieve this.

You can sniff the `$http` request and response between to do whatever you want and return the $q unscathed.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', 'mathScriptLoadError', function($q, mathScriptLoadError) {
                        return {

                            requestError: function(rejection){                            
                                mathScriptLoadError.anyError(rejection);    
                                return $q.reject(rejection);
                            },

                            responseError: function(rejection){                            
                                mathScriptLoadError.anyError(rejection);
                                return $q.reject(rejection);
                            }
                        };
    }]);
```

In the above code I get the `anyError` function of the factory `mathScriptLoadError` to inspect the `rejection` and invoke some process based on values. But this doesn't disturb the `$http.get` at any level.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated.
>     Use the standard `then` method instead.
>     If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to
>     `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.

-- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- Deprecation Notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

Tell your mates: `"From now on guys use $http.get(url).then is cooler!"`

---

For other readers:

## Response Interceptors

The AngularJS framework provides three places to inject response interceptor functions.

- The `$http` service, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).
- The `$resource` service, see [AngularJS $resource Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).
- Configuring the `$httpProvider`, see [AngularJS $httpProvider API -- interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#interceptors).

XHR responses can be intercepted and modified globally, locally, or by class.

Comment: Please use comments for additional discussions related to the question.

Comment: @CharlieH Added information that answers the question.